# Binding to a property of an object through object[property] rather than object.property

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, ironpython

I've read through the WPF Data Binding Overview and I *feel* like this should be possible but I can't quite make the mental leap here. I know that if I set a binding's `Path` to `foo`, and set the `Source` to `obj`, then the binding will look at `obj.foo`. In other words, `obj.__getattr__()` will be accessed.

**All I want is to make it look at `obj[foo]` instead.** I'm using Ironpython and in this case my `obj` class has an overridden `__getitem__()` that calls a member function and returns a value, which is why I need this functionality.

Here is the above example written programmatically. This displays the `foo` property of `obj` in a checkbox:

```
myBinding = Binding("foo")
myBinding.Source = obj          
acheckbox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, myBinding)
```

---

### Solution

It's as simple as this, apparently!

```
myBinding = Binding("[foo]")
myBinding.Source = obj          
acheckbox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, myBinding)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use that in a binding, e.g. if my `DataContext`/source has a property

```
public string this[int i]
{
    get{...}
    set{...}
}
```

you can create a binding like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding [0]}"/>
```

**Edit:** I feel like i might have misunderstood your question, if so please tell me.

Comment: Whoa, is it really that simple? Will setting the binding path to `[foo]` and the source to `obj` make the binding access `obj[foo]`?

Comment: I'm having trouble with NotifyPropertyChanged not updating its target and I think it's due to the path being `[foo]`. The binding correctly updates its source (actually, its datacontext), but if I change the property in code and then call `OnPropertyChanged("foo")`, the target doesn't update. On a hunch I even tried changing the call to `OnPropertyChanged("[foo]")` but it still doesn't work. Any ideas? I'll move this to a separate question if needed.

Comment: Call `OnPropertyChanged(Binding.IndexerName)`, see if that works.

Comment: Unbelievably, it works. I was mystified as to what sort of far-flung voodoo magic this was and found this post: http://10rem.net/blog/2010/03/08/wpf---silverlight-quick-tip-inotifypropertychanged-for-indexer - apparently it's a constant, `"Item[]"`, that tells the binding engine to rescan the whole dictionary. Unfortunately this happens to be an expensive operation in my code... so that post also talks about using `"Item["+key+"]"` as the argument. This is exactly what I need - and it doesn't work! Only `Item[]` works. I think I'll have to take this to a question of its own...