# Updating a binding that is bound to object[property] (Binding.IndexerName weirdness)

Tags: python, wpf, binding, ironpython, inotifypropertychanged

This emerged from my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947758/binding-to-a-property-of-an-object-through-objectproperty-rather-than-object-pr). I currently have the following binding:

```
myBinding = Binding("[foo]")
myBinding.Mode = System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.TwoWay
myBinding.Source = obj          
acheckbox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, myBinding)
acheckbox.DataContext = obj
```

This will look at `obj[foo]`. The UI will update the source just fine - I can check the checkbox and `obj[foo]` is changed. However, the reverse is not working. Changing `obj[foo]` in code does not update the UI, even with this code manually calling `OnPropertyChanged`:

```
obj[foo] = False
obj._OnPropertyChanged(obj, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("[foo]"))
```

The problem likely lies with the arguments to `OnPropertyChanged`. Some digging (and help from H.B.) revealed this post:
http://10rem.net/blog/2010/03/08/wpf---silverlight-quick-tip-inotifypropertychanged-for-indexer

> If you're creating the data source for
>   those (for example, you are building
>   your own ObservableDictionary), you
>   may wonder how on earth you fire the
>   appropriate
>   `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`
>   event to let the binding system know
>   that the item with that field name or
>   index has changed.
>
> The binding system
>   is looking for a property named
>   `"Item[]"`, defined by the constant
>   string `Binding.IndexerName`.

In other words, `Binding.IndexerName` is a constant, `"Item[]"`, that tells the binding engine to rescan the whole source dictionary.

```
obj._OnPropertyChanged(obj, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(Binding.IndexerName))
# equivalent to:
obj._OnPropertyChanged(obj, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"))
```

Unfortunately, scanning the entire source dictionary happens to be an expensive operation in my code; so that post also talks about using `"Item[foo]"` as the argument. This is exactly what I need - and it doesn't work! Only `Item[]` works. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to mamadero2 in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/75994a09-2e82-4440-82dc-47aa7979ced3) `Item[index]` only works in Silverlight 4.

(I never would have imagined that Silverlight supports something that WPF does not)

Comment: I doubt it since the binding mechanics are quite internal.

Comment: Looks like I have to go back to overriding `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`, then. LAME